# Problems with SSL(django-sslserver) on Django project

Tags: python, django, ssl

I am using `Django 1.6.2` in `virtualenv`, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. As I wanted to shift my project  to `https`, I installed [`django-sslserver`](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver).
 The project needs self signing, and works fine for Home Page. However, apps in my django project encounter problems. Not all pages are redirected to `https`, and hence causes 404 error (works only if explicitly prefixed as `https`).   Also, the overall template (appearance i.e. static files?) is lost. 
What exactly is happening here? How to make sure that all pages are redirected to `https` and works the same way as in `http`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited:** My pull request has been merged.  Static resources are served normally now.

The problem is that the `runsslserver` command is not implemented to serve static resources.  A way to fix is to override `get_handler` in `PATH_TO_PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGE/sslserver/management/commands/runsslserver.py` like so:

```
# ...
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
from django import get_version

# ...

class Command(runserver.Command):
    # ...

    help = "Run a Django development server over HTTPS"

    def get_handler(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Returns the static files serving handler wrapping the default handler,
        if static files should be served. Otherwise just returns the default
        handler.

        """
        handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
        use_static_handler = options.get('use_static_handler', True)
        insecure_serving = options.get('insecure_serving', False)
        if use_static_handler:
            return StaticFilesHandler(handler)
        return handler

    # ...
```

You might want to get your site package path with

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

I've also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver/pull/17/files) in case you want to branch, merge, and reinstall it as a package on your own.

Cheers